# NSTextField not losing focus when it has text, even if I click other TextFields in the view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, focus, nstextfield

I am having some problem in giving focus to my password NSTextField, when my username textfield has focus and I have typed something. When I click password textfield, nothing happens and focus remains with username textfield. 
Now when I clear the text in username textfield and then click password field, focus is switching as it should.

So simply, **I am not able to switch focus to password textfield (by any method, clicking, hitting tab etc) if username textfield has focus, and has text. If I clear text, I can switch without any problem.**

### My Project Setup

This is my view structure

```
MainViewController (subclass of NSViewController)
    |
    |
 Window (NSWindow)
    |
    |
     ------ LoginView (Subclass of NSView)
    |            |
    |            |
    |             ------ UsernameTextField (NSTextField)
    |            |
    |            |
    |             ------ PasswordTextField (NSTextField)
    |
    |
     ------ MainView (subclass of NSView)
    |
    | 
  And other views (NSView)
```

I have 3 screens in my app, and I have created 3 NSView subclasses to draw these views. LoginView is the first of those view. LoginView has the 2 textfields in question.

I am doing the entire UI using interface builder so there is nothing much to show in code.

This is how I am adding the LoginView to MainViewController's window

```
@implementation MainViewController
------
------
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [[self window] setContentSize:[self.loginView frame].size];
    [[[self window] contentView] addSubview:self.loginView];
    [[[self window] contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];
}
----
----
@end
```

I have tried to implement NSTextFieldDelegate,

```
@implementation LoginView
-----
-----

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor{
    return YES;
}
-----
-----
@end
```

These methods gets called whenever the focus switches. But in the case when there is no focus switch delegate methods are not firing.

Any idea?

Comment: Remove yourself as the delegate of those two fields.  Does that fix your focus switching issues?

Comment: @CodaFi nope.. There was no delegate initially.. I just added it after I had this problem..

Comment: Are you sure you didn't actually turn off the text field's ability to accept first responder status?

Comment: If you are talking about "Refuses First Responder" check box in IB, then it is unchecked for both textfields. More over, if it is checked, then it shouldn't work when there is no text in username field. right?

Comment: @uchuugaka can you explain. I am not setting anything for setNextKeyView field. I never thought about it.

Comment: BTW I must add that, when I click password field first and type some text, I can switch to username field. But once focus is on username field (with text) then there is no way to take it away.

Comment: @uchuugaka **nextKeyView** property for both textfield is empty right now.. I haven't set anything to it

Comment: Read up on the responder chain and key view loop. It might get you some insight.

Comment: Okay. No answers yet. I worked around, by removing the textfields in Xib. And I added the textfield's in code. Now it is working as it should be. I am not posting this as answer, since this is not an answer in anyway.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Hey I ran into a similar problem. I think you have accidentally selected 'NSTextField with Number Formatter' in Interface Builder for Username instead of the regular NSTextField. If you enter numbers in your Username field you should be able to go out of it. To fix the problem you can select the normal NSTextField in Interface Builder which is just below Label.